# can in compile the jdk from the src.zip included in the Java SE for WIndows

Tags: java

I wish to compile the JDK for a custom CPU. As far as I know, src.zip is made available with the Oracle Java SE 1.3 package.

Can I compile JDK 1.3 (for eg.) using the src.zip? Can I do this in a regular Eclipse/Netbeans project?

Comment: Your best bet is to compile one of the OpenJDK releases for your custom CPU and upgrade whatever Java program you want to run on them to be compatible with that release.

Comment: Why? The JDK is already platform-independent. What you need is a JVM and some native classes, and they and their frameworks aren't present in src.zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I compile the Java SE 1.3 from the src.zip included in the Java SE for Windows.

No you can't.

The src.zip file only includes the public classes in the `java.*` packages.  (And possibly some of the `javax.*` packages.)  AFAIK, it doesn't include the `com.sun` packages, and others that comprise internal APIs.  And it certainly doesn't include the Java source code for the JDK tool chain; e.g. the Java  compiler, the javadoc tool and so on.

One way to see what is missing would be to compare the contents of `src.zip` with the compiled zip and jar files in the JRE install.

And the `src.zip` doesn't include any of the native code implementation of the JVM; e.g. the JIT compiler, the garbage collector, the native libraries for threads, i/o, and so on.

---

The complete source code for Java SE 1.3 was only available to 3rd-party Java vendors under a special license.  AFAIK, the license fee was substantial.  Java 1.3 was never released as open source.

If you want something that you could consider porting Java to a custom CPU, you would need to start with OpenJDK.  But it will not be simply a matter of recompiling Java code.

Comment: When porting the JDK to an entirely new CPU then [Project Zero](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/zero/) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, having just 'src.zip' is not enough for JDK build.

Building JDK from source is actually complicated process, you'll need to install native C++ compiler and some build tools: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ihse/demo-new-build-readme/common/doc/building.html

So answer for second part:

> Can I do this in a regular Eclipse/Netbeans project?

is also no.